# Random Functions

Tags: functions, random-functions

In computers or to be more specific programming, I can call for a "random" function which generates "random" numbers. How does it do this? Is there a mathematical function that produces eratic and almost seemingly "random" numbers?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: Not a mathematical answer, but [GNU/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), and now some other Unices (such as OSX), use [/dev/random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random), which acquires randomness from the user's asynchronous activities (key presses, mouse movements, ...).

Comment: Wow! I've never heard that before, that's pretty cool @AndrewD.Hwang.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a [pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). In essence, it starts with some deterministic value (a seed), does some computations on it, and gets some seemingly random output.